# How to display the user-defined-symbollist (addins) in access?

Tags: ms-access, ribbon

I support an old access-applications with a ribbon-menu with "Add-Ins". I don't know exactly but this app could be 10 years old. There are several "custom designed" buttons *(DATEN ANSEHEN, Export nach Excel, DATEN FILTERN, ...)*:

[image]

Now a client is missing the buttons: [image]

He is the only person of 20 clients who have this problem. He uses Windows 10 with Office 365 like everybody else.

How to show the buttons for the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compared this file to the file which is in use of other clients and saw following lines missing:

```
    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "------------------- DATEN --------------------", A_TOOLBAR_YES
    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "----- BEARBEITEN -----", A_TOOLBAR_YES
```

Now the buttons are available again